# List view Header is not clickable

Tags: android, listview

This is my custom layout, I set this as my list view header, and has some function to do when it is clicked, but the thing is only when the view inside the layout is clickable, rest does not responds

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/Gray"
android:clickable="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/customPhotoLayout"
        style="@style/listItemMarginStyle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/custom_circle_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_circle_height">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/custom_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/custom_image_description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_first_letter"
            style="@style/customInitialStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_custom_name"
        style="@style/myProfileStyle"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/custom_list_item_padding_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/custom_list_item_padding_vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/customPhotoLayout"
        android:text="@string/default_my_custom_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_list_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/custom_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_custom_profile"
        style="@style/mycustomStyle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_custom_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/custom_list_item_padding_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/custom_list_item_padding_horizontal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/customPhotoLayout"
        android:text="@string/my_custom_profile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

only this view is clickable not the above part

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@color/separator_color" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have not specified attributes `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` in two text views just above View. Isn't it giving error??

Comment: more over you are using relative layout but you are not specifying the position of your `View` view in layout file. So the `View` specified in the end is being rendered above all other views. So give it a attribute `android:layout_below = "@id/my_custom_layout"`

Comment: tried android:layout_below = "@+id/my_custom_layout", still i could click only the views @Dhruvam

Comment: layout_width and layout_height are specified in the styles @Dhruvam

Comment: give relative positions to `ImageView` and `TextView` also in inner `Relative Layout`

Comment: In relative layout you will have to specify position of every view . Are you a beginner?? if yes then please [read this once](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)@Ganesh

Comment: still i don't see the entire header clickable, only the view is clickable

Comment: what is header here according to you?? Can you please post your modified layout file ??

Comment: mHeaderView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_header, null);

Comment: mListView.addHeaderView(mHeaderView, null, true); mHeaderView.setClickable(true);

Comment: this is how i set the header to my list view. but the header is not clickable still

Comment: i can't tell you the exact problem. you need to post your complete code in question. By seeing only one or two line i can't help you. So please edit your question with complete code `i.e. Activity Class code` aslo